# Sublime Text 3: Regular expression replacement fails on quotation marks in snippet

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I wrote a custom snippet for commenting code, and the regex within it fails whenever there is a space followed by a single or double quotation mark:

```
<snippet>
<content>
<![CDATA[
/*========================${0/./=/g}
  =            $0            =
  ========================${0/./=/g}*/
]]>
</content>
<tabTrigger>comment-block</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

What the regex does is replace the input with an equals sign (`=`) to make it look like a fancy comment block. But whenever a space followed by any quotation mark is encountered, it stops replacing text and breaks the comment block.

Try it yourself by loading the snippet, typing `comment-block` and hitting Tab, then typing "This is a ' comment block".  It will break when it encounters the single quotation.

How can I go about properly escaping the `'` and `"` to make this work?  Adding backslashes before the `.` does nothing.

Comment: Could you explain where you are using that regex? Surely, not in Find and Replace, right?

Comment: @stribizhev Updating my main post with the full snippet now.

Comment: I tested some more, and it looks like it fails with any character that is auto-matched - `'`, `"`, `(`, `[`, `{`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have a solution, but this was just filed recently as a known [issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1017), so it's not just you. It seems that if any snippet (including auto-matching) is triggered within the substitution regex, the regex just quits. I confirmed the issue on both OS X 10.10 and Ubuntu 15.10, using the latest [development build](http://sublimetext.com/3dev) of Sublime, so it hasn't been fixed since the most recent public beta was released.

I'll keep playing around with and see if I can come up with a workaround, but for now I guess we'll just have to live with it.